# Do closed questions get more down-votes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, closed-questions, up-votes

I observed that my questions that got closed got more down-votes after closing and more up-votes before closing.

Can someone query the SO data to see if there are more down-votes than up-votes after a question is  closed and thus see if there is a general trend here?

Comment: You can look at your timeline to see what happened in what order: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/192821/eduard-florinescu?tab=reputation&sort=time

Comment: @Fluffeh I was thinking more like a general statistics if someone that knows how to query the SO data could do that.

Comment: They probably are. See, we have such a useful golden badge as Electorate here... and it's easier to give a totally unbiased opinion on the question that is already considered a bad thing by community.

Comment: Re your remark "my questions got more down votes after closing and more positive votes before closing", ehm, are you saying your questions get closed very often? If so, then maybe they are bad quality, and they do deserve downvotes.

Comment: Can it be that it has been closed for a longer time than it was open?

Comment: @BoPerson I am talkin about ratios, percents not absolute numbers.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Percentages are also highly misleading with such small absolute numbers (both in number of examples, and number of votes per example).  It would be more meaningful to look at absolute numbers.  Anyway, to address the question, the most worrying problem that I see here is people upvoting close-worthy questions.  If a question is bad enough to be closed it usually shouldn't be getting upvotes.

Comment: @Servy if people keep vote down a question even if there is an answer to it and you cannot delete it, you then hope for a few upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Questions with close votes, are visible in review lists. So they get more attention and as such probably more votes.

Comment: But you now can't downvote from the review lists; it takes effort to downvote.